# How can I change my python path permanently?

Tags: python, django

I recently just installed Inkscape to my Windows 10 computer, and it changed my python path.

```
C:\Users\Chinyere\Documents\Django Files\Commercial>python
Python 3.8.9 (default, Apr 13 2021, 15:54:59)  [GCC 10.2.0 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', 'C:\\Program Files\\Inkscape\\lib\\python38.zip', 'C:\\Program Files\\Inkscape\\lib\\python3.8', 'C:\\Program Files\\Inkscape\\lib\\python3.8\\lib-dynload', 'C:\\Program Files\\Inkscape\\lib\\python3.8\\site-packages']
```

I can't run my Django files. When I try, it pops-up error

```
C:\Users\Chinyere\Documents\Django Files\Commercial>python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 12, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Please, how can I change it to the default python path without uninstalling Inkscape.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling python? Can you afford it. I mean, if you have some packages installed, can you again install them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall Inkscape and reinstall.
While reinstalling Inkscape, be sure to uncheck "add to path" if it is checked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First, you can try install the package again. If you can not install it again try to reinstall your python.

*Note: You should use virtual environment in python so it is easier to manage your library. After finished, you can note what library you use and install all the library by once.

```
py -m pip freeze
```

( Virtual Env: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html
Pip freeze : https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze/ )